# Chrome inspect, cant locate element by xpath I just copied

Tags: html, google-chrome, web, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a spinner icon poping up dynamically on page indicating page is loading, I need to detect when it disappears (this bit is clear for me)

Every time I click on this spinner inside google chrome inspect, and I press copy xpath, I get this one:

```
/html/body/vr-root/vr-route-handler/vr-layout/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/div/bs-campus/div/div/bs-data-grid/div/div[2]/mat-spinner/svg/circle
```

But when I try to locate this element (even inside Chrome inspect tool pressing CTR+F, it does not find it.

Is there any different way to locate it? I have tried to search it with relative xpath, but it fails too:

```
.//div/mat-spinner
```

Edit: added picture

[image]

Edit 2: when I pause page in Chrome Inspect -> Source -> Pause script execution, I am able to search and find (ctr+f) element in chrome inspect by:

```
.//mat-spinner
```

but when page is running (and element is still visible) it cant be located.

Error log while trying to access it with webdriver

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: .//div/mat-spinner (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:113)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:283)
        at base.StaticSeleniumDriver.getWebElement(StaticSeleniumDriver.java:362)
        at steps.BaseSteps.debugDrawSpinner(BaseSteps.java:55)
        at ?.Given Debug draw spinner(Campus.feature:190)
      Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: .//div/mat-spinner
      For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
      Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
      System info: host: 'BANNB061', ip: '10.0.75.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
      Driver info: driver.version: StaticSeleniumDriver
```

Using following code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpath)));
```

Comment: Share your code for the same. Also try to click any element on page while spinner visible and check exception - HTML for spinner might be present in log (share this HTML also)

Comment: Is the element visible when you are looking for it. And how it shows and hides? What technology do you use?

Comment: @Andersson sorry but I cant share whole html (its from work) unfortunately

Comment: No, I mean HTML for `div` with spinner and code you're using to handle it

Comment: @kamentk I am creating automation tests using selenium web driver, but it is not very relevant now, the main issue is that: 1. I make sure element is visible (spinner) 2. I copy its xPath using chrome inspect tool 3. I make sure element is visible again (spinner) 4. while element is still visible, I am pressing CTR + F in chrome inspection tool, searching for element with xPath i previously copies, but even though xPath is same, it does not detect it. Thank you

Comment: @Andersson I have just edited my post with screenshot, will try to copy html of this element too.

Comment: Update the question with the HTML (properly formatted), not a picture.

Comment: Can you share code you're using and exception log?

Comment: Have you tried CSS selectors like "mat-spinner" or "mat-spinner[role='progressbar']"?

Comment: If you want to test CSS selectors in the browser, use `$$("mat-spinner")`, etc. in the Chrome dev console. For XPaths, use `$x(...)`.

Comment: Maybe it is into a frame and because of that you cannot find it.

Comment: @Andersson - added error log and code I am using to access element with selenium webdriver, but I am not sure how is that relevant because I once again repeat, I can not locate this element using inspect tool in chrome even using same xpath i copied from this element, thank you.

Comment: @MateuszMysliwiec , can you check whether mat-spinner located inside an iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that i made in protractor.
My logic is to check if spinner is present after interaction with the website.
Example: click on element, type some text, page navigation .. popup etc..
you can find the proper place where to put it.
Hope it helps, you can adapt it to any language. selenium API is common.

Note if you have find the **.//mat-spinner** use it as xpath for element.

```
export async function handleSpinner() {
    console.log('Checking if loading spinner is present on the page.');

    let spinner = element(by.css('div.spinner'));
    try {
        // setting minimal timeout to search for the element
        await browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(500);

        // trigger check if there is such element on the page. will throw exception if not present
        await spinner.getWebElement();

        console.log('Spinner has been found.. waiting.... up to 10 seconds.');
        await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(spinner), 10000, 'Spinner is still present...');
        console.log('Spinner has disappeared.');
    } catch (ex) {
        // spiner is not present so ignore the exception
    } finally {
        // Setting browser implicit timeout back to the original configuration.
        await browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000);
    }
}
```